# How to remove material UI ripple left padding

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I am using material UI card component to create a notes page using ReactJS, but on clicking on the card the ripple leaves some padding towards the left. I want the ripple to be visible throughout the card, as shown in the docs. Here is the pic of how the card looks when active:

[image: Current result]

And here is the code:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 345,
  },
  media: {
    height: 140,
  },
});

export default function MediaCard() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className='notes-container'>
      <form className='search'>
        <input className='search-bar' type='search'></input>
        <button className='btn-sml-2' type='submit'>
          search
        </button>
      </form>
      <ul className='notes-showcase'>
        {NotesList.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index}>
              <Card className={classes.root}>
                <CardActionArea>
                  <CardMedia
                    style={{ height: 10, paddingTop: "56.25%" }}
                    className={classes.media}
                    image='https://cdn.crispedge.com/4d91c6.png'
                    title=''
                  />
                  <CardContent>
                    <Typography gutterBottom variant='h5' component='h2'>
                      {item.title}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography
                      variant='body2'
                      color='textSecondary'
                      component='p'
                    >
                      {item.chapter}
                    </Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                </CardActionArea>
                <CardActions>
                  <Button size='small' color='primary'>
                    Share
                  </Button>
                  <Button size='small' color='primary'>
                    Open
                  </Button>
                  <Button size='small' color='primary'>
                    Download
                  </Button>
                </CardActions>
              </Card>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      <AddNew name='notes' />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It seems fine. Can you reproduce the problem online( for example as a sandbox link)?

Comment: Nvm solved it, there was a css span styling that had some margin set and the MUI ripple effect was also using the span tag, hence the weird margin. Thanks